# Unexpected T_EXIT

Tags: php

I got a parse error (unexpected T_EXIT) on line 1 when I run this code (it's in a file used for AJAX):

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['nickname']) || !isset($_POST['password']))
    die('{"result": "error", "message": "Ouch"}');
// [...]
?>
```

if, however, I put a char between the first 2 line (like a space after "<?php" or a tab before "if"), it works fine.

I don't understand, it never happened to me before.
I checked the file in hexa mode to see if there were some strange and undesired invisible character but everything seems normal.

Does somebody already have this error or know how to solve it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: my first thought was to check line endings in your php editor

Comment: The code itself has no problems

Comment: Check your line endings. It's possible that there isn't a \n after <?php

Comment: Could you give the **EXACT ERROR MESSAGE**, not how you remember it, and the EXACT CODE, because what you've shown works just fine: http://ideone.com/hrDKX

Comment: Are you using the old Mac OS 9 `\r` line-endings? If you are using Windows, install [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org), open the file, then click Edit -> EOL Conversion -> UNIX Format and see if your file works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shaquin Trifonoff and others said, my line endings were not in Unix version.
Strange thing this didn't cause me any problem before that, or maybe it changed recently for a mysterious reason.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Say how you solved it in your answer, not in your question

Comment: Mh yeah sorry. In fact at first I couldn't write an answer before a certain time as I'm new, so I did it like this (in the question), but sure that's better now. Thanks